# Unable to replace White space in CSV in Python (Webscrape results)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, whitespace

I'm working on cleaning a dataframe of a CSV of a web scrape I did on LinkedIn Job Postings. I first incorporated a **str.strip().replace(' ', '')** to remove trailing/leading whitespace plus spaces in between the trailing/leading as well. This worked for most rows in my "Job Description" column, but there were some that had massive leftover whitespaces. (Something like this:

```
8. This range is provided by EVONA. Your actual pay will be based on your skills and experience —talk with your recruiter to learn more.                   
9.                                               ThisrangeisprovidedbyEPITEC.Youractualpaywillbebasedonyou

10. This range is provided by EPITEC. Your actual pay will be based on your skills and experience —talk with your recruiter to learn more.
```

Next I tried adding in a regular expression to remove all whitespace to see if this would at least remove all whitespaces **.str.replace(r'\s+', '', regex=True)**      but this only removed all the whitespace in the rows that were already working properly. The result looked something like the following:

```
7.HarderMechanicalContractorshasanopeningforamechanicaldesignertosupportourclientsandconstructiontea
8...........................................................................................................................Actualpaymaybedifferent—t **the periods represent whitespace**
9.Description:*SolidworksreadblueprintsanddrawingsfromcustomerproducesketchsheetsAS-1100,CNCAerospacepartsSkills:*Solidworks,mechanicalengineering,readblueprints,pipeline,DesignAdditionalSkills&Qualifications:*Solidwork
```

I'll attach my current script below. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and thank you in advanced!

```
import pandas as pd

path_to_file = '/Users/Desk/Desktop/Desk/mechanical_engineer_LinkedIn_test_scrape.csv'

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 300)

data = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)

data['Seniority'] = data['Seniority'].str.strip()
data['Seniority'] = data['Seniority'].replace('Full-time', 'N/A')
data['Job Description'] = data['Job Description'].str.strip().replace(' ', '')
data['Job Description'] = data['Job Description'].str.replace(r'\s+', '', regex=True)
#print(data.iloc[0:500, 6])
#print(data.head(100))
print(data['Job Description'].head(50))
```

Comment: You need to use something like `ord` to figure out what those characters are.  Maybe they are Unicode non-breakable spaces that aren't being recognized as whitespace.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thank you for the suggestion, I went in and changed one of the dataframe rows to string format and ran a for loop for the ord of all the characters inside. For the giant whitespace sections, it returned 32. According to RealPython, the unicode code 32 is 'SP (Space)'. So it seems that they are spaces. Maybe my code that changes it to string is wrong? This is what I used

string = (data.iloc[[2], [5]].to_string(header=False, index=False))
for char in range(0, 200):
    print(ord(string[char]))